# Hide user on login screen for kubuntu and lubuntu [19.04]

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, users, login-screen

so I tried to use what has worked for me for years as below.
But trying this on both of these flavors of ubuntu gives an error on giving the gdm user x server access.

Sequence:
  Use root:

sudo -i

Enable gdm to access x11:

```
    xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
  su gdm:
    su gdm -l -s /bin/bash
  hide users:
    gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
```

Error:

```
localuser:gdm being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0xd
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  9
root@kubuntudt:~# su gdm -l -s /bin/bash
su: user gdm does not exist
```

Why?
How to fix?

Thank you in advance!
Bill

Comment: Neither Kubuntu nor Lubuntu use `gdm`; Lubuntu uses `sddm`, as does I believe Kubuntu too.  `gdm`=gnome display manager so why would Kubuntu/Lubuntu be expected to have `gdm` setup

Comment: fyi:  if it worked before for you, it was because you did something differently; as those distros using `gdm` doesn't make sense - neither use gnome, nor GTK+  (though lubuntu did use older GTK+2 in the past)

Comment: And both Kubuntu and Lubuntu 19.04 use *sddm* by default. Without further explanation of how *gdm* figures in the equation, I'm afraid this question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry if I mis-stated, all prior implementations were using ubuntu not kubuntu or lubuntu, which from the responses would be the reason why it is not working... So the bigger question is how would I do it on these flavors?